# How to pass a ko.observablearray via JSON to an MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout JS to build a model to pass to an MVC controller. The ko.observable() items are passed to the controller no problem, however, the ko.observableArray([]) data is appearing as "count=0" at the controller.

Below is the object I am building in my View:

```
var AddViewModel = function () {

self.ModelRequest = {
    Object: {
                VarArray: ko.observableArray([]),
                Var1: ko.observable(""),
                Var2: ko.observable("")
                }
    };

....
```

The ModelRequest.Object.VarArray is an ko.observableArray contains a few attributes in the object: Name, Id, Code, Type.

Below is how I'm sending the data via JSON:

```
p = ko.toJSON(AddViewModel.ModelRequest);
debugger;

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: ko.toJSON(AddViewModel.ModelRequest),
    success: function (data) { 
       ...something...
    }
});
```

When I am debugging the code, I examine the p variable described above and I see the below:

```
{"Object":{"VarArray":[{"Name":"Name 1", "Id":2, "Code":"50.1", "Type":"A"}], 
"Var1":"abc", "Var2":"def"}}
```

When I examine the object being passed into the controller, Var1 and Var2 have the correct values, however, the VarArray is "Count=0".

Any thoughts? Thanks for taking the time to look at this. I'll try any ideas at this point!!

EDIT 10/6/13:
This is my controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public CRUDResponse AddItem(AddRequest ModelRequest)
{
   ... something here ...
}
```

At this point when I examine the ModelRequest I see that VarArray is "Count = 0".

Edit 10/8/13:
This is the details of the AddRequest:

```
#region Public Members

public ObjectType Object { get; set; }

#endregion Public Members
```

Where the ObjectType is:

```
#region Public Members

public int Var1 { get; set; }
public int Var2 { get; set; }
public List<SpecType> VarArray { get; set; }

#endregion Public Members
```

Where the SpecType is

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Code { get; set; }
public FieldType Type { get; protected set; }
```

And the FieldType is a Enum.

**UPDATE:** I had just found the problem. It looks like the property is not getting serialized properly through JSON when I make a call to my Web API from the UI. The above-mentioned property is of type TypaA which inherits from TypeB. TypeB contains all of the fields needed by TypeA. When I change the property failing to serialize to be of type TypeB, instead of TypeA, it serializes just fine and I get all of the values I need reflected in Web API.

So, basically, JSON fails to serialize a value if it's type is derived from another type. Removing the inheritance by declaring a value to be of base type fixes the issue.

So, is there a way to serialize a property whose type inherits from another class?

Eric

Comment: Can you show your controller action? Are there any ModelState errors?

Comment: I added the controller action to the above posting. I don't have any ModelState errors.

Comment: Thanks-- what does the class `AddRequest` look like?

Comment: Andrew, please see the modifications I made to the post. Hopefully this answers your question. If not, let me know what else I can provide that can help. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that in `p = ko.toJSON(AddViewModel.ModelRequest);`, the `AddViewModel` constructor has a property `ModelRequest`. Perhaps you want to use the `ModelRequest` property on an object created with the constructor instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that either A: you are never populating the observableArray, or B: you are not receiving the proper object type back on the controller, either because you are sending it incorrectly or receiving it improperly.

Try doing this -

```
function testData(name) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = ko.observable(name);
}
```

inside of your view model

```
var AddViewModel = function () {
    self.ModelRequest = {
        Object: {
            varArray: ko.observableArray([
                new testData('Your my boy blue'),
                new testData('Frank the tank')
        ]),
        var1: ko.observable(""),
        var2: ko.observable("")
        }
    };
}
```

And see if your controller action is actually getting your data back.

If not then you are most likely not matching the object you are sending to the controller with an object the controller recognizes.

Comment: Hi PW, thanks for your response. I am sure I am populating the observable array as I examine the model prior to sending the model to the controller via JSON. I'll try your suggestion you included to see if I am loading the object type properly. I'll let you know what happens. Thanks again for your suggestion!